# WM8960 on Pi detected but not working

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, i2s, audio-codec, pcm

I am trying to create custom board with WM8960 IC with Raspberry Pi. I am able to use Wolfson drivers for pi to detect the IC via I2C but I am not able to play or record any audio. This is the schematics.

[image: Sch]

I am able to use Seed Studio Respeaker pi Hat with same drivers but not able to use my custom board. I2C device is indeed detected. So it is not problem with detection. Is there something missing or some pre-settings needs to be done?

Comment: This CODEC chip has a lot of status registers. Have you configured these to the way you need them to be?

Comment: I am using it the way i use re-speaker hat by letting drivers set-up resisters.